# Java Security Framework

Tags: security, frameworks, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jaas

Security always tends to take the last place in a new project. Or you use a framework like Spring where security is already build-in and can be switched on easily.
I try to find an open security framework that can be plugged-in to both Swing and Web applications (and JavaFX?), maybe easy to digest. I looked at plain JAAS, JGuard and JSecurity but its just too complicated to get started.
Any recommendations or experience to share ?
I am working with NB, Glassfish and MySQL.
Thanks
Sven

Comment: Changed tag from jee5 to javaee, because you shouldn't limit yourself to the latest version!

Answer (score 8):

I have just taken a view of this http://shiro.apache.org/

> Apache Shiro is a powerful and
>   easy-to-use Java security framework
>   that performs authentication,
>   authorization, cryptography, and
>   session management. With Shiro’s
>   easy-to-understand API, you can
>   quickly and easily secure any
>   application – from the smallest mobile
>   applications to the largest web and
>   enterprise applications.

Answer (score 5):

I would strongly recommend learning `JAAS`.  It really isn't that difficult to pick up, and there are some useful [tutorials](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jaas/tutorials/index.html) and a [reference guide](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jaas/JAASRefGuide.html) on the Sun web site.

In my experience, `JAAS` is pretty widely used, so it's definitely something you'll be able to reuse once you're learnt it.  It also happens to be one of the building blocks for the [Glassfish](https://glassfish.dev.java.net/javaee5/security/faq.html#pluglogin) authentication mechanism!

Answer (score 5):

I have done a similar research in JAAS for web application and has ran into a "mind roadblock" until I finally realize JAAS is a framework addressing security at a different "layer" then traditional web applications in the Java World. It is build to tackle security issues in J2SE not J2EE.

JAAS is a security framework build for securing things at a much lower level then web-application. Some example of these things are code and resources available at the JVM level, hence all these ability to set policy files in the JVM level.

However, since J2EE is build on top of J2SE, a few modules from JAAS was reuse in J2EE security such as the LoginModules and Callbacks.

On the other hand, Acegi, aka Spring Security, tackles a much higher "layer" in the securing web-application problem. It is build on top of J2EE security hence J2SE hence JAAS. Unless you are looking to secure resources in the J2SE level (classes, System resources), I don't see any real use of JAAS other than the using the common class and interfaces. Just focus on using Acegi or plain old J2EE security which solves a lot of common web application security problems.

At the end of the day, it is important to learn which "layer" of the J2EE-J2SE security issue you are tackling and choose the write tool(s) for the problem.

Comment: After some time looking at the options, I believe JSecurity (now called Ki (http://incubator.apache.org/ki/) is a good choice. Still under development but what I tested so far, looks promising.

Comment: ki is now called shiro, just a note for outcomers

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend you take a look at OACC (http://oaccframework.org). OACC was designed for solving the problem of application security. Unlike most frameworks OACC is able to store/manage the authorization relationships in your application. OACC's authorization model is more powerful that Shiro or Spring Security.

Answer (score 2):

There is alternative from JBoss. A new version for PicketBox. More information here:
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/SECURITY/Java+Application+Security

Answer (score 0):

apache shiro miserably fails when you stress a web application under JBoss (say 2 million requests of a simple GET with a concurrency of 50 threads).
was very dissapointing to find out this.
it happens when you use filters.

Comment: This is unfounded without further evidence.  I've used Shiro in mission critical web applications that handle hundreds of thousands of requests per second.  There are networking projects that use Shiro to secure network endpoints that handle hundreds of millions of requests daily. I suspect your internal architecture or data stores that sat behind Shiro was causing a problem.  I can assure you from very real experience that Shiro can scale extremely well.

Answer (score 0):

You can read http://code4reference.com/2013/08/guest-posttop-java-security-frameworks-for-developing-defensive-java-applications/

It gives 1000mile view from various Java Security framework, such as JAAS, Shiro or Spring Security. All are depended on your requirements and technology stacks that you choose